# Difference between guest star and special guest star

Tags: production, credits

What's the difference between the 2 roles in TV credits, I noticed that the **special** is given to a more famous player, is it true? Is there a definitive answer?

Comment: I suspect there is more to this than even what the answer linked above describes. I know that sometimes major actors in bit parts are unbilled so that the producers don't have to follow SAG rules and pay them, but recently I noticed that "with" credits don't always follow much of a quantifiable logic because in Glass Onion, Kate Hudson got a "with" credit and she's in literally the entire film as a premier cast member yet was not billed as one of the "starring" roles. Sadly, it may actually be as stated in the answer below, it's what your agent can negotiate.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive answer is going to be rather disappointing, I'm afraid.

It depends on what your agent can negotiate.
Nothing more, nothing less.